# Is there anyway to get heat to use a file genereated by heat as a source for guids?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I've just started looking at wix again now that it looks like installer projects are going to be deprecated from VisualStudio. We have a third party application that is "install via xcopy", which makes it hard for us to track in terms of versioning so we'd like to create an msi for it. There are several hundred files that are part of the installation.

I'd like to use heat to create the list of files for the installer, but I've heard that it's not good to use heat to create the wxs file more than once with autoguids because then your installer will have issues.

I was wondering if in wix 3.6, there was a command line parameter to heat which would take a previously generated wxs file as the source for guids? I want heat to autogenerate guids for any new files, but use the previous output of heat as a database for existing files.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-ag` flag this will set the guids to be generated at compile time and as long as the path doesn't change the compiler will keep the same guid for each component. Rather than use a command-line to do the harvesting it is better to edit the `*.wixproj` file and add a [HeatDirectory](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild_task_reference_heatdirectory.htm) element.